# How to stop Jquery jCarousel on a specific condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jcarousel

I am working on jquery's jCarousel, In which i am having some images from database and shown as slider using jCarousel, my functionality is working as per i expected but i want to apply one  more functionality is that if image is only 1, then it should not do sliding, I am taking image count from database then setting it in jCarousel visible property

```
$('.carousel').jCarouselLite({
            visible: @ViewData["ImgTotalCount"].ToString(), 
            activeClass: 'current',
            btnNext: ".carousel-next",
            btnPrev: ".carousel-prev",
            auto: 2000,
            speed: 600  

        });
```

curently it is sliding even on one image

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one image, set the auto parameter to null. It will restore it to its default value, and to its default behavior, which is not moving.

See documentation here : http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/#doc

Comment: Images are coming from database and images count varies on diff situations

Comment: So you are refreshing images with ajax ? Is it what you mean ? Do you you want to refresh images every X minutes without page reload ?

Comment: So you are refreshing images with ajax ? Is it what you mean ? Do you you want to refresh images every X minutes without page reload ? If yes, then can you try to delete the carousel and create a new one each time. // If not, you can modify a javascript variable in your html page (within script tags, assign it autovar = <value in asp.net>) and make sure that you load the carousel on onload (aka when the page has finished loading). You can then set the auto parameter with a variable.